# Reloading a page after sending a form POST don't work but with GET yes

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

thanks for reading my problem and sorry if my english is not perfect.

So, my problem is when i send a form via ajax with the method post, my page bug when reloading. After some test, i found that if i use the method get, everything works fine. I don't get it. Also, if i comment the select part, it works even with post.

Here is my code: 
The ajax function:

```
    function showDispo(){

            validate($('#frmUpdateTaux'));
        }
    function validate(form) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "updateDispo.php"
                , data: $(form).serialize()
                , datatype: 'json'
                , type: 'post'
                , error: function(error, errmsg){
                    alert(errmsg + ' :=: ' + error.responseText );
                }
                , success: function(Data) {
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            });
        }
```

and my html code:

```
<form method="get" id="frmUpdateTaux">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">

            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <label class="lbl" id="lblMois" name="lblMois" for="lstMois">Mois :</label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <select id="lstMois" name="lstMois" size="1">
                        <option value="1">Janvier</option>
                        <option value="2">Février</option>
                        <option value="3">Mars</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td align="left"  colspan="2">
                <input type="button" id="btnGenerate" name="btnGenerate" value="Mettre à jour" onclick="showDispo()">
                </td>
            </tr>
    </form>
```

UpdateDispo.php

```
require_once("BD.php"); $month= $_POST["lstMois"]; /*query */ $insertNewIndispo ='...' //execution of the query
```

//QUERY INSERT
$insertNewIndispo ='...'

$exec = BD::run($insertNewIndispo, BD::QUERY_INSERT, false, false);

FYI: I want to reload the page to display the results of a query run in this page and new values are inserted in the DB table by UpdateDispo.php

Do you have an idea where the problem comes from?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post `updateDispo.php`? Perhaps there's something in there that's puking when you use POST instead of GET.

Comment: It's done, but i just get the value and use it in my query.

Comment: If you plan to reload the page, why use ajax instead of a regular form submission?

Comment: Oh, i'm stupid some times...I go try that

Comment: I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps the problem you have is the following:

```
<form method="get" id="frmUpdateTaux">
```

How can you get $_POST if you are sending $_GET?

If you want to use ajax, then try:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" id="frmUpdateTaux">
```

Then you can use your ajax code to catch the variables you are sending.

Btw: For ajax I use the following code to catch form data:

```
    // First declare your variables by their ID.
    var lstMois = document.getElementById('lstMois').value;
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "put here your filename(can be the same as the one you are currently browsing)");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                // Do something.
                } else {
                // Something went wrong, alert them.
                alert("Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.")
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("lstMois="+lstMois);
}
```

Then you should have php code in the page you are referring to, which will have something like this:

```
$lstMois = $_POST['lstMois'];
// Do whatever you want with it.
// If everything went well:
echo "succes";
exit();
```

The ajax code will see php has sent 'succes' to it, and will do whatever you say in

```
if(ajax.responseText == "success"){

}
```

PS. Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Have you tried removing: ' method="get" ' And replace it with ' onsubmit="return false;" '?

Comment: ok it's working now. I think it's because of the exit();
Thanks !

Comment: No problem, Hope you won't have any more problems :).